# How to loop CSS animation on SVG tag

Tags: html, css, loops, svg, stroke

So my code works perfectly fine, it creates a stroke animation on `<svg>` tag!

The problem is that the animation repeat only once (when I refresh the page)

I want to infinity loop the animation but I don't know how!

```css
   body{
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    #logo{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        animation: fill 0.6s ease forwards 1.3s;
    
    }
    
    #logo path:nth-child(1) {
            stroke-dasharray: 788.711181640625px;
            stroke-dashoffset: 788.711181640625px;
        animation: line-anim 1.2s ease forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes line-anim{
        to{
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
    }
    
    
    @keyframes fill {
        from{
            fill: transparent;
        }
        
        to{
            fill: white;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="logo" width="313" height="302" viewBox="0 0 313 302" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M223.4 157.2C232.2 160.1 237 169.6 234.1 178.4C231.8 185.3 225.4 189.9 218.2 189.9C211.2 189.9 205 185.6 202.5 179.1H184.7C182.3 179.1 180.2 177.5 179.4 175.3L173.9 158.8L156.6 219.4C155.9 221.8 153.7 223.4 151.2 223.4H150.9C148.3 223.3 146.1 221.3 145.7 218.8L127.8 111.3L114.7 174.9C114.1 177.4 111.9 179.1 109.3 179.1H84.2C81.1 179.2 78.5 176.8 78.4 173.7C78.3 170.6 80.7 168 83.7 167.9C83.9 167.9 84 167.9 84.2 167.9H104.9L123.4 82.4C124.1 79.4 127.2 77.5 130.2 78.3C132.4 78.8 134.1 80.7 134.4 82.9L152.7 192.5L168.2 138.3C168.9 136 171 134.3 173.4 134.3H173.5C175.9 134.3 178 135.9 178.8 138.1L188.7 167.9H202.3C205.1 159.1 214.6 154.3 223.4 157.2Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
    <path d="M313 85.4C313 113.2 300.8 152.7 277.1 185.1C231.9 247 156.7 301.1 156.7 301.1C156.7 301.1 81.5 247 36.3 185.1C12.5 152.6 0.399994 113.2 0.399994 85.4C0.399994 38.8 38 0.9 84.6 0.5H85.4C115.2 0.5 141.6 16.3 156.8 39.6C172 16.3 198.4 0.5 228.2 0.5H229C275.5 0.9 313 38.8 313 85.4ZM234.1 178.4C237 169.6 232.2 160.1 223.4 157.2C214.6 154.3 205.1 159.1 202.2 167.9H188.6L178.7 138.1C177.9 135.8 175.8 134.3 173.4 134.3H173.3C170.9 134.3 168.7 136 168.1 138.3L152.6 192.5L134.3 82.9C133.9 80.6 132.3 78.8 130.1 78.3C127.1 77.6 124 79.4 123.3 82.4L104.8 167.9H84.1C83.9 167.9 83.8 167.9 83.6 167.9C80.5 168 78.1 170.6 78.3 173.7C78.4 176.8 81 179.2 84.1 179.1H109.2C111.8 179.1 114 177.4 114.6 174.9L127.7 111.3L145.6 218.8C146 221.4 148.2 223.3 150.8 223.4H151.1C153.6 223.4 155.8 221.8 156.5 219.4L173.8 158.8L179.3 175.3C180.1 177.6 182.2 179.1 184.6 179.1H202.4C204.9 185.6 211.1 189.9 218.1 189.9C225.4 189.9 231.8 185.3 234.1 178.4Z" fill="#6C63FF"/>
    </svg>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `infinite` prop to your animation:

```
#logo path:nth-child(1) {
        stroke-dasharray: 788.711181640625px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 788.711181640625px;
        animation: line-anim 1.2s ease forwards infinite;
}
```